# T-SQL Output to JSON Not Working As Expected

Tags: json, t-sql

I have three tables that I want to combine and output in a JSON document. Table1 is the parent and it has two children Table2 and Table3.

I am struggling getting JSON to format like this

```
{
"Table1": [
    {
        "DOC_ID": 201300624951,
        "DOC_DESCR": null,
        "Table2": [
            {
                "DOC_ID": 201300624951,
                "DOC_DESCR": null,
                "PAY_ACCT_NO": null,
                "APPLY_TO_DOC_NO": null,
                "APPLY_TO_DOC_DAT": null,
                "APPLY_TO_DOC_TYP": null,
                "PAY_APPLY_METH": null,
                "PAY_AMT": null,
                "DwCreateDate": null
            }
        ],
        "Table3": [
            {
                "DOC_ID": 201300624951,
                "PKG_TRK_SEQ_NO": null,
                "PKG_TRK_NO": null,
                "DwCreateDate": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

where DOC_ID is the key that ties all tables together.

I appreciate any help and I can provide sample data if its needed. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  When asking a question about SQL you should provide a relevant set of sample data (preferably the DML to create it) and the code you've tried so far.  You can edit your question to include that and it will very much help you to get a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select *,
 (select * from table2 where table1.doc_id=table2.doc_id for json path, include_null_values) as Table2,
 (select * from table3 where table1.doc_id=table3.doc_id for json path, include_null_values) as Table3
from table1
for json path, root('Table1'), include_null_values
```